# How to pass value to JavaScript closure from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am new to JavaScript prototype and closure, following is my code:

```
function setFontSize(size) {        
    return function() {
        console.log("font size: "+size+ " setFontSize()");      
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}
function setFontSizeInput(ipval) {
    console.log("font size ipval : "+ipval);
    var fontsizeIP= setFontSize(ipval);
}
window.onload = function() {
    var fontsize18 = setFontSize(18);
var fontsize14 = setFontSize(14);
var fontsize16 = setFontSize(16);
document.getElementById('size-18').onclick = fontsize18;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = fontsize14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = fontsize16;
}
```

On `onkeyup` event I am calling `setFontSizeInput`, as the user enters value in input field I want to change fontsize so I have created new object of `setFontSize(ipval)` and passed input field value, but it not reflecting. Any idea whats wrong in my code?

[For JSFiddle Click](http://jsfiddle.net/techprasad/WxKJs/)

Comment: Seems to be working ("Closures Demo Practival Closures" changes in size when I click on the buttons), could you provide more details as to what's meant to happen?

Comment: why onkeyup event ? clearly nothing is happening on keyup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript  was not loaded into the document because of some bug in http://jsfiddle.net/ codes, also after getting the function you should call it "fontsizeIP(ipval);" , try this way and put it in HTML editor and remove all from JavaScript editor:

```
   <script>
      function setFontSize(size) {      
          return function() {
              console.log("font size: "+size+ " setFontSize()");        
              document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
          };
      }
      function setFontSizeInput(ipval) {
         console.log("font size ipval : "+ipval);
         var fontsizeIP= setFontSize(ipval);
         fontsizeIP(ipval);
      }

      var fontsize18 = setFontSize(18);
      var fontsize14 = setFontSize(14);
      var fontsize16 = setFontSize(16);
      document.getElementById('size-18').onclick = fontsize18;
      document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = fontsize14;
      document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = fontsize16;

   </script>
   Closures Demo
   <br>
   Practival Closures
   <a href="#" id="size-18">18</a>
   <a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
   <a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
   <input type="text" id="inputFontSize" placeholder="Enter Font Size" onKeyUp="setFontSizeInput(this.value);">
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code as follows:

```
function setFontSizeInput(ipval) {
    console.log("font size ipval : " + ipval);
    setFontSize(ipval)();
}
```

Note `()` after `setFontSize(ipval)`. They are needed since `setFontSize` returns function.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WxKJs/2/

I would also recommend to use some little delay before you change font size to avoid flickering of the font from, say, 1 to 12 when you type 12:

```
function setFontSizeInput(ipval) {
    delay(setFontSize(ipval));
}

var delay = (function() {
    var delay = 100, timer;
    return function(callback) {
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, delay);
    };
})();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WxKJs/3/

Comment: Also note that if using JSFiddle "No wrap - in <body>" need to be specified in the options on the left. Leaving the default "onLoad" will wrap the javascript code inside a window.load() event and it won't be possible to call it from html

Comment: @f.cipriani Correct, otherwise all defined functions are local scope and not globally available.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a bit to make better use of closures. Here is a link to the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WxKJs/7/

I made FontSize a class which stores a local value of the font size that was sent to the constructor. I gave it a `set` method that will allow you to override and set a new font size if a value is passed as a parameter. As a safety check you would probably want to check that your font size is an int before you actually try and save/set it.

```
function FontSize(size) {
    var self = this;
    function isInteger(value) {
        return (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Integer]');
    }
    function isNumber(value) {
        return (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Number]');
    }
    function isMouseEvent(value) {
        return (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object MouseEvent]');
    }
    function getInt(value) {
        var val = parseInt(value, 10);
        if (isNaN(val)) return 12;  // return a default number
        if (isInteger(val)) return val;  // return int
        if (isNumber(val)) return Math.round(val);  // convert to int
        return null;
    }
    self.fontSize = getInt(size);  // our default font size, defined at construction
    self.set = function (override) {
        var fontSize = self.fontSize;
        if (override && !isMouseEvent(override)) {
            fontSize = getInt(override);  // if it's not a mouse event get override
        }
        console.log("font size:", self.fontSize, ", override font size:", fontSize);    
      document.body.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
    };
}
function setFontSizeInput(ipval) {
  console.log("font size ipval : "+ipval);
    var inputFontSize = new FontSize(ipval);
    inputFontSize.set();
}

var fontsize18 = new FontSize(18);
var fontsize14 = new FontSize(14);
var fontsize16 = new FontSize(16);
document.getElementById('size-18').onclick = fontsize18.set;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = fontsize14.set;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = fontsize16.set;
```